# Is there a difference between wrongly delivered and delivered by mistake?

Tags: word-usage, difference

In my opinion, I think wrongly delivered can mean both something that you didn't order got to your house and something you ordered went to your neighbors. And delivered by mistake means that it is delivered but it's not something you ordered, the point in this phrase is that it's delivered.Is this understanding right?
I don't if I am clear, but I do feel like I can say it's wrongly delivered when a customer find out the package was delivered to their neighbor by mistake.
Is it ok to say that? And is it going to be weird?

Comment: *wrongly* can mean *by mistake*, but it can also mean *intentionally contrary to rule or agreement*.

Comment: You could also say "it was misdelivered.", whether it was by mistake or intentional.

Answer (score 1):

> 'wrongly delivered' and 'delivered by mistake'

As @Anton commented, 'wrongly' encompasses a wider set of meaning, including intentional act as in the 2nd definition below.

Google defines it as

> wrongly
> /ˈrɒŋli/

> adverb
> adverb: wrongly
> 1.
> in a way that is incorrect or mistaken.
> "my name is spelled wrongly"

> 2. 
>
> in an unjust, dishonest, or immoral way.